# Importing external joomla site in newly installed joomla

Tags: joomla, xampp

How to **import my external joomla website(saved in folder)** to another newly installed joomla in localhost without any joomla extension?

Comment: Probably better to ask on [joomla.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the template, import the data via the database (SQL-import) and modify your configuration.php in root folder for new connection.

Thats it in most cases, just try and tell us if something went wrong.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. i copied old site template directory into the newly installed joomla but no use

Comment: "No use" is not specific enough. What error did you get? Did you modify the configuration file to reflect the changed location? Did you export the old database and import it to a new empty database and change the config to reflect that?

Comment: Templates must be installed, not just copied. Again: you dont need a new installed joomla if you want your old (saved in folder) to run. Copy the files from your folder to your host AND after that you have to IMPORT your OLD DATABASE BACKUP into your host's DB-System. After that: go to your previews copied folder on your host and add the db connection data to the config.php. (Again: Old files to ftp, old database backup to host and thats it)